# Is it possible to get an estimate of children of RecyclerView.Adapter count before adding items in android?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Is it possible to get an **estimate** of children of RecyclerView.Adapter count before adding items in android?

What I would want is that I want to **estimate** the children count of an Adapter before adding items to it so that I could estimate the visible items I could only insert.

Like for Example a Tablet

1. A Tablet can have many children view than a Phone
2. A Phone could have lesser children than a Tablet

Getting an estimate how many children or items (is an advantage for my case) I can add to the adapter so that it fits visibly at first population of my data to my adapter.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#getItemCount()

Comment: What do you mean? There is already the [`getItemCount()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#getItemCount()) method you had to override when building your adapter. Is there something else you're after?

Comment: i think of a guess.. say u have a viewholder object; inOncreateViewHolder function u get parent right.. from that u can try to get all childs ; not sure

Comment: @PPartisan hmm my question is quite vague, I wanted to estimate first before adding some items in my adapter.

Answer (score 1):

This might work. It should return all child views of your ViewHolder that are visible. You could also try it by replacing `firstItem` with `0` and `lastItem` with `recyclerView.getAdapter().getItemCount()`:

```
private static int getRecyclerViewChildCount(RecyclerView recyclerView) {

    //This below section is a bit clumsy, but the findFirstVisibleItem() etc. methods
    //Only apply to LinearLayoutManagers and their subclasses.
    try { 
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = (LinearLayoutManager) recyclerView.getLayoutManager(); 
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("LayoutManager must be of type " + LinearLayoutManager.class.getSimpleName());
    }

    final int firstItem = layoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPositiob();
    final int lastItem = layoutManager.recyclverView.getLayoutManager().findLastVisibleItemPosition();

    int viewCount = 0;

    for (int i = firstItem; i < lastItem; i++) {
        View view = recyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(i).itemView;
        viewCount += view.getChildCount();
    }

    return viewCount;
}
```

Comment: What I would really want @PPartisan is an estimate, I see you get the findLastVisible and Last to get the total, but in my case I have no children yet in my adapter so I actually would want an estimate. But the question is it possible?

Comment: you can estimate the no of  children before set in adapter by:- you are sending data to adapter object in list, array or in any way you can get the no of children by size of list or length of array

Comment: @david I'm a bit confused in that case. Could you put some sample code in your question to help visualise your problem? If you know the size of your dataset and the number of children in your `ViewHolder` then of course it's just a case of multiplying one by the other.

Comment: @PPartisan hmm thats a good point actually. It's just a matter of how i represent it by mathematically then i can deduce the no. of items I can populate.